# ¿Cómo hago una petición POST a un objeto dentro de otro objeto, con Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito subir a una db de firebase una clase *Restaurante* con otra clase dentro *Menus*. Mi objetivo es después poder retornar esa información de *Restaurante* con sus *Menus*.

**MODELO DEL RESTAURANTE**

```
Restaurant restaurantFromJson(String str) => Restaurant.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String restaurantToJson(Restaurant data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Restaurant {
    Restaurant({
        this.name,
        this.menu,
    });

    String name;
    List<Menu> menus;

    factory Restaurant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Restaurant(
        name: json["name"],
        menu: List<Menu>.from(json["menu"].map((x) => Menu.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "menu": List<dynamic>.from(menu.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Menu{
    Menu({
        this.name,
        this.price,
        this.descrip,
    });

    String name;
    int price;
    String descrip;

    factory Menu.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Menu(
        name: json["name"],
        price: json["price"],
        descrip: json["descrip"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "price": price,
        "descrip": descrip,
    };
}
```

**PROVIDER (PETICION)**

```
class RestaurantProvider{  //El puente entre el firebase y mi app

  final String _url = "https://comida-d20f0-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com";

  Future<bool> createRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) async{

    final url = "$_url/restaurants.json";

    final resp = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: restaurantToJson(restaurant));

    final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);

    print(decodedData);

    return true;
  }
```

**INTENTO DE RETORNO** Esto es un código de prueba para ver si me funciona el POST pero creo que acá es donde estoy fallando... Cuando mando a llamar el `createRestaurant`

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _textEditingController2 = new TextEditingController();

final restProv =  RestaurantProvider();
final restaurant = Restaurant();

TextField(controller: _textEditingController), // Coloca el nombre del restaurante

TextField(controller: _textEditingController2,), // Coloca el nombre de 1 Menu del restaurante

FloatingActionButton(
            child: Text('Ok'), 
            onPressed: (){    
               restaurant.name= _textEditingController.text; // Nombre del restaurante
               restaurant.menu[0].name = _textEditingController2.text; //Nombre de 1 Menú

               restProv.createRestaurant(restaurant);
            },
          )
```

Si hay algo que no se llegara a entender, háganmelo saber, estoy hace varios días con esto y no logro encontrar respuesta; arranqué hace muy poco con Dart y Flutter.

Comment: por que no usas los plugins de firebase y firestore para eso?